# Did I flag this properly?

Tags: discussion

[How to create an EAV entity?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/how-to-create-an-eav-entity)

First off, I think Marius is a Magento genius, and I mean no disrespect.  But isn't the fact that his answer has to be split into 6 parts indicative of it being too long for this format?

Can they be combined in a community wiki, or will it still take up 6 parts?

Is there perhaps a way to host the code dump elsewhere and have links to the parts explaining which does what?

Comment: Just curious....what did you flag it as? Or what was the reason you voted to close?

Comment: I flagged it as "Too Broad" which specifically states "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: @Marius I wonder....Do you think it would be better to ask separate questions for some of the parts, then link  to those parts from the parent question?  Just brainstorming

Comment: What would be great would be a kind of community driven tutorials section to this site for longer essentially tutorials like this

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as a general thing, you should flag everything that doesn't seam right to you....EVERYTHING.

Second...about the post you mentioned.... There is alimit of 30k characters for each answer. I could have made the code available somewhere else, but off site resources could be gone anytime. That's why I posted the code here.

...And I already made parts 2-6 community wikis. 
I would love if all of them would be put into one answer,  but I think the problem is the way the answers are stored. There may be a limit in the database.